# Limits of functions as $x$ tends to infinity

Tags: calculus

While defining the limits of functions as $x \to \infty$ we say that if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $M$ such that whenever $x>M$ we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$  then $L$ is the limit of the function as $x \to \infty$
$$$$ But I want to know that what if $f(x)$ is not defined for $x>N$ for some $N$

Comment: Then the limit $x \rightarrow \infty$ is not defined.

Comment: Then what is the necessary and sufficient condition under which the limit is defined as $x \to \infty$

Answer (score 2):

If there exists $N$ such that $f(x)$ is not defined for all $x>N$, then you cannot take the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$. This is similar to the case of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ where $a$ must be a limit point of the domain of $f$.